# about rxjava request url

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have four Http Url, I need to try one by one.But there is a problem,when one of the url is error,the after url not call. The pseudocode like this:
i = 0;

```
 Observable.fromArray("http://www.baidu.com/", "http://www.google.com/", "https://www.bing.com/")
                    .concatMap(new Function<String, ObservableSource<String>>() {
                        @Override
                        public ObservableSource<String> apply(String s) throws Exception {
                            return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) throws Exception {
                                    Log.i("settingsubscribe", i + "");
                                    if (i == 1) {
                                        emitter.onError(new Throwable("error"));

                                        //emitter.onComplete();
                                    } else {
                                        emitter.onNext(s.concat("_1"));
                                        emitter.onComplete();
                                    }
                                    i ++;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    })

                    .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(String s) throws Exception {
                            Log.i("settingfffff", s);
                        }
                    }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                            Log.i("settingfffff", throwable.getMessage());
                        }
                    }, new Action() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() throws Exception {
                            Log.i("settingfffff", "onComplete");
                        }
                    });
```

when i = 1,send the error and the event stoped, I hope continue, How can I do?

Comment: See http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#concatMapDelayError-io.reactivex.functions.Function-

Answer (score 0):

`emitter.onError(new Throwable("error"));`

in above line of code, onError you are  creating new Throwable, instead can you just log the error